# Program in Jade Running on Netbeans not Transferring Message

Tags: java, netbeans, agents-jade

I have created an agent which accepts a value and then passes a message on to the next agent.  I am having problem with entering a value and so my message is also not being transfered.  Here is my `Agent` class, below.  Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

```
public class Prgm extends Agent {

        int val;

        protected void setup() {
                Objects[] args = getArguments();
                if (args!=null && args.length > 0)
                        val = Integer.parseInt((String) args[0]);
                addBehaviour(new OneShotBehaviour(this) {
                        public void action() {
                                if (val == 1) {
                                        ACLMessage msg = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
                                        msg.setLanguage("english");
                                        msg.SetOntology("DG Status");
                                        msg.SetContent("DG connected");
                                        msg.addReceiver(new AID("r1", AID.ISLOCALNAME));
                                        myAgent.send(msg);
                                } else {
                                        ACLMessage msg = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
                                        msg.addReceiver(new AID("r1", AID.ISLOCALNAME));
                                        msg.setLanguage("english");
                                        msg.setOntology("DG Status");
                                        msg.setContent("DG not connected");
                                        send(msg);
                                }
                        }
                });

        }
```

Comment: What does `getArguments()` do?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use ontologies right away don't. For strings you can use:

```
ACLmessage.setContent("string message") and String stringmsg=ACLmessage.getContent()
```

If you need something more try Java serialization, it's way simpler than using ontologies.

Also I don't think this line is acceptable. `new AID("r1", AID.ISLOCALNAME)`. One would typically contact the df (directory facilitator) agent querying available agents or services. Try something like this

```
DFAgentDescription template = new DFAgentDescription();
    ServiceDescription sd= new ServiceDescription();
    sd.setType(Service);
    sd.setName(agentName);

    template.addServices(sd);

    try {
        DFAgentDescription[] result = DFService.search(this, template);
        listAgents.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i<result.length;++i)
        {
            listAgents.addElement(result[i].getName());

        }
        //System.out.println(listAgents);

    } catch (FIPAException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        log(this.getAID() +"!!error in requesting service ="+Service);
    }

    return (AID) listAgents.get(0);
```